# Where can I obtain a complete listing of all NS-based classes (Cocoa)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Where can I obtain a complete listing of all NS-based classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I recall, the Foundation, AppKit and Core Data frameworks contain all of the non-deprecated NS* classes. You can find the references for [Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001091), [AppKit](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/index.html), and [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001181) on developer.apple.com or in the documentation installed locally with the Apple Developer Tools (use Xcode's Help->Documentation). For a list of all of the "Cocoa" frameworks, start [here](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/API_Fundamentals/Cocoa-api-date.html).

Comment: Oops. looks like I missed Core Data. Thanks for adding that in there, Barry.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode -> Help -> Documentation: look under AppKit Reference and Foundation Reference. I'm sure there's similar documentation on apple's dev website.

Answer (score 1):

You will find an overview of both [Foundation class hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH3-SW40) and [Application Kit class hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH3-SW41) (grouped by topics) in the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app that Andy Lee wrote that is very useful for quick method reference, called AppKiDo:

http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads/appkido.html

It gives you the option of including individual frameworks in your search results.

Comment: Awesome tip, I tried it out and it's really good.  Thanks Evan.

Comment: See also "Cocoa Browser Air", a more modern AppKiDo-like Cocoa documentation browser: http://numata.designed.jp/en/programming/cocoa-browser-air.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is a nice app.  Much faster too!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to bang out a list of ALL objective c based classes just open up terminal a run

```
grep -Rho "@interface [a-zA-Z]\+" /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms | cut -d" " -f2 | awk '!a[$0]++' | sort
```

You will need Xcode installed.
This will take a while but covers all platforms (macOS, tvOS, watchOS etc).
To just target a particular platform adjust the path accordingly.
So for just macOS change:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
```

to:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```

or you could narrow it further to a particular framework. This will also work for protocols. Just change the @interface for @protocol.